# XNA C# object texture

Tags: xna, textures

I have a question about xna. I got a sample fbx file from MSDN (the ship with texture) when i put it in my code ( i followed it on MSDN) it works fine also with texture, but then when i put my own model (cube with minecraft dirtblock texture) it only shows the cube, not the texture. The program doesn't give me any error.

Comment: I made my model with 3Ds max, then export it to .fbx (also I export texture)

Comment: Does the texture shows up black? If so your texture might be facing the wrong way, or have an incorrect normal.